# Html helpers no longer able to infer type arguments

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

Full error text:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

It just recently started happening, though I don't believe I made any changes that would affect this functionality.  It throws VS intellisense error, but the pages function just fine.

Html helpers that are not "For" helpers work just fine, it's only the ones that contain these expressions.

The offending markup(1 example of 100s):

```
 <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PortfolioName) %>
```

Page Directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="ViewPage<My.Namespace.PortfolioViewModel>" %>
```

View Model:

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class PortfolioViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Portfolio Name:* ")]
        public string PortfolioName { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `It throws error on compile, but the pages function just fine`? How can the pages work if you are not able to compile? Is it just a Visual Studio Intellisense error in design mode?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Should have been more clear.

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate the issue. What happens if you try to explicitly specify the type arguments?

Comment: I believe the issue is outside of the code supplied, as it is pretty much just textbook MVC stuff.  I have not tried to explicitly specify the type arguments.  I imagine it would work, but I have literally hundreds of these things throughout my solution.

Comment: Having the same issue. Seems to be isolated to MVC2 for me. I've moved some projects to MVC3 and this problem goes away.

Comment: +1 @Ryan, did you ever resolve this? If so, how?

Comment: @Dommer Yes I did, but I'm struggling to remember how at the moment.  I *think* it had something to do with ambiguous references to System.Web.Mvc.  I was referencing a .dll but also had another version installed in GAC.  I don't remember if that was exactly it, but it was close.

Comment: Please tell me how this issue got fixed. I am having same issue.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds stupid, I know, but have you tried closing and reopening VS?

Comment: Oh ya, I've tried closing/reopening, clean/rebuild, quadruple checked all my references, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this problem previously, it was after we upgraded MVC versions and the web.config references were not properly updated.  This meant that the views were relying on references to older versions of the HTML extension methods.

Look at your  references and ensure that the version is correct.

Comment: Can you explain in a more layman term so that a beginner can also fix this issue. Kindly elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

The `Html.DisplayFor` method will find a suitable display template for the specified type. The exception seems a little odd but it might indicate that no display template have been registered for the string type.

You might want to try `Html.LabelFor` for testing purposes. Do you have a special display template for strings?

Comment: I have the same result with DisplayFor, HiddenFor, TextboxFor, DropDownListFor, etc, etc, etc

Comment: I just did a quick test projekt. MVC will print the raw text to the html stream if no special display template exists. At least for string that is the case.